# Android-x86 8.1 installed from Linux .rpm not fully booting - looping log entries

Tags: boot, linux-mint, android-x86

I recently downloaded the .rpm package for Android x86 8.1, used Alien to convert to a .deb, and installed it (after modifying the post-config script to use `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` instead of `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` for the menu entries). However, when it boots, it gets stuck on several failed tasks.

If i select `Android x86 8.1` in the GRUB menu, then it gets stuck on a screen with an underscore. If I select `Android x86 8.1 (DEBUG mode)`, it displays tons of errors. With both, it never made it to the boot logo.

Here are the log entries it has been looping on.

```
[  669.206600] modprobe: netdev-dummy0
[  669.206699] type-1400 audit(153301730 956:1730) avc: denied { getattr } for pid=8559 comm="netd" path="/vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=363 scontext=u:r:netd:s0
[  669.343896] modprobe: dummy0 [  672.349605] init: starting service "cameraserver"...
[  672.343896] init: property_set("ro.boottime.cameraserver", "671915327209") failed: property already set
[  672.358466] init: couldn't write 8598 to /dev/cpuset/camera-daemon/tasks: No such file or directory
[  672.702811] init: starting service 'media'...
[  672.718181] init: property_set("ro.boottime.media, "672275478248") failed: property already set
[  672.729461] init: couldn't write 8598 to /dev/cpuset/foreground/tasks: No space left on device
[  672.967430] init: starting service 'surfaceflinger'...
[  672.984282] init: property_set("ro.boottime.surfaceflinger", "672541344661") failed: property slready set
[  672.996160] init: Failed to bind socket 'pdx/system/vr/display/client': No such file or directory
[  672.996425] init: Failed to bind socket 'pdx/system/vr/display/manager': No such file or directory
[  673.483713] type=1400 audit(1533017035.153:1745): avc: denied { read } for pid=8599 name="vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=363 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tmpfs:s0 tclass=Ink_file permissive=1
[  673.552332] type=1400 audit(1533017035.322:1746): avc: denied { read } for pid=8600 comm="system-server-i" name="vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=363 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tmpfs:s0 tclass=Ink_file permissive=1
[  678.578389] type=1400 audit(1533017040.416:1789): avc: denied { open } for pid=8599 comm="surfaceflinger" path="/dev/tty0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7383 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  678.578389] type=1400 audit(1533017040.416:1790): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=8693 comm="surfaceflinger" path="/dev/tty0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7383 ioctlcmd=0x4b3a scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  678.578530] type=1400 audit(1533017040.416:1790): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=8693 comm="surfaceflinger" path="/dev/tty0" dev="tmpfs" ino=7383 ioctlcmd=0x4b3a scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  678.578545] type=1400 audit(1533017040.416:1791): avc: denied { sys_tty_config } for pid=8693 comm="surfaceflinger" capability=26 ino=7383 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1
[  678.707414] input: Android Power Button as /devices/virtual/input/input27
[  678.715346] type=1400 audit(1533017040.416:1791): avc: denied { sys_tty_config } for pid=8693 comm="surfaceflinger" capability=26 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tty_device:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1
[  678.715356] type=1400 audit(1533017040.546:1792): avc: denied { write } for pid=8694 comm="system_server" name="uinput" dev="tmpfs" ino=8331 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:uhid_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  678.852574] binder_alloc: 8694: binder_alloc_buf, no vma
[  678.861176] 8692:8692 transaction failed 29189/-3, size 88-0 line 3141
[  679.228876] x_tables: ip_tables: owner match: used from hooks INPUT, but only valid for OUTPUT/POSTROUTING
[  679.228876] x_tables: ip6_tables: owner match: used from hooks INPUT, but only valid for OUTPUT/POSTROUTING
```

It starts repeating those lines on screen infinitely.

I also found the system log in `/android-8.1-rc1/data/log.txt` and [uploaded it](https://nofile.io/f/bqZFmQ4xoUN/log.txt).

Is there some way I can fix this?

My system is an HP 10 TS Notebook PC (e010nr) (no hardware changes).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same issue, did you ever fix it? It's driving me nuts and it doesnt seem to be the main issue everyone has with forcing VESA modes as I have been don that rabbit hole of fixes and this is the ONLY listed result for the exact same issue I could find after extensive searching.